# Entity framework 5 : create entity type for association table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using entity framework 5 ,
the problem is that EF5 does not create EntityType for tables which contains only foreign keys 
which is not the case with EF4

does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

to workaround, i added a column to tables containing only foreign keys, i generate the edmx, and i removed them after from my edmx and the DB

thank's in advance for your help

Comment: Can you confirm please - the table containing only FK's is implementing a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: yes, it's a many-to-many relashionship

Comment: Sorry, I thought that this might be relevant... I tried creating an entity model in both EF5 and EF4 but both time, I got no entity for the link table. Can you tell me the steps with EF4 that gave you the third table please? BTW, the code classes that are generated look ok - there are navigational collections that should handle the M2M relationship. Can you also tell me why you want an entity for the link table? Cheers.

Comment: why would you need an entity type for the join table?

Comment: In fact , in my application i have to historize the modifications made on the DB. for that, i have another DB which contains the same tables , plus additional columns used for historization like user name ...
so what i'm doing is , on the save changes method i look for the modfications and i add them to the hisrorization DB, before inserting them in the DB
with T4 , i generate the code that convert an entity to historizable entity, so for each table i need to have an entity corresponding on my model

Comment: @Ackroydd I'm using VS2012 , .NET 4.5
To force VS to use EF4, in the edmx designer , i set "Code generation Strategy" to "Default" ,i delete the ".tt" files 
in this case, VS generate entities for the association tables

Answer (score -1):

They're not created because they're unnecessary - you should deal directly with the navigation properties at each end of the relationship.